# Read XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am trying to read XML using simplexml_load_file. Following is my XML:

```
<map_style>
    <background_color>FFFFFF</background_color>         

    <state_color>c5d577</state_color>
    <label_color>212121</label_color>

    <state_hover_color>AECE13</state_hover_color>
    <label_hover_color>FFFFFF</label_hover_color>

    <state_inactive_color>dbe99c</state_inactive_color>
    <label_inactive_color>212121</label_inactive_color>

    <stroke_color>AECE13</stroke_color>

    <lake_color>ffffff</lake_color>
    <lake_stroke_color>ffffff</lake_stroke_color>

    <other_color>FFFFFF</other_color>
    <other_stroke_color>FFFFFF</other_stroke_color>
</map_style>

<!------for map on home page---------------->
<mapstyle_home mapOutlineColor="c2da78" mapRollOverColor="AECE13" mapGradientColor="AECE13"></mapstyle_home>

<!------for featured properties settings---------------->
<featured_property_style>
    <layout width="203" height="182" background="#FFFFFF" imageBackground="#aec565" showGrid="1" autoPlayDefault="1" />
    <buttons navigationDots="1" playPause="1" />
    <text option="1" />
<featured_property_style>
```

I can read XML till `</map_style>`. However, as soon as I add:

```
<!------for map on home page---------------->
<mapstyle_home mapOutlineColor="c2da78" mapRollOverColor="AECE13" mapGradientColor="AECE13"></mapstyle_home>

<!------for featured properties settings---------------->
<featured_property_style>
    <layout width="203" height="182" background="#FFFFFF" imageBackground="#aec565" showGrid="1" autoPlayDefault="1" />
    <buttons navigationDots="1" playPause="1" />
    <text option="1" />
<featured_property_style>
```

And try to read XML then it gives an error.

Following is my code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($strCurlUrl);

    //$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($strCurlUrl);

    //echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";
    $this->m_arrXml = array();
    foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
      //echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
      $this->m_arrXml[$child->getName()] = $child;

    }
```

where `$strCurlUrl` is above xml file.

Comment: However, as soon as I add .... what?

Comment: He completed the question with a piece of source that was not there before!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your XML is invalid. XML always requires exactly one Root-Node! In your example there are three of them...